# @Option with enum List does not accept candidates that ${COMPLETION-CANDIDATES} shows

Tags: java, picocli

I have an `@Option` with an enum `java.util.List` and [picocli](https://picocli.info/) just does not accept candidates that the `${COMPLETION-CANDIDATES}` shows.

The way how `picocli` shows and accepts values does not align with each other.

**Code:**

```
@CommandLine.Option(
    names = {"-c", "--columns-to-hide"},
    description = "Comma separated list of column names that won't be displayed"
            + "%nCandidates: ${COMPLETION-CANDIDATES}",
    split = ",")
final List<Header> columnsToHide = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Rendered help:**

```
-c, --columns-to-hide   Comma separated list of column names that won't be displayed
                        Candidates: PORTFOLIO, TICKER, TYPE, CREATED, VOLUME, PRICE, FEE, TRANSFER_ID
```

The following error appears when I try to use multiply candidates as it was shown in the help:

**Command:**

```
java -jar my.jar ... -i "PORTFOLIO, TICKER, TYPE"
```

**Error:**

```
Invalid value for option '--columns-to-hide' (<columnsToHide>): expected one of [PORTFOLIO, TICKER, TYPE, CREATED, VOLUME, PRICE, FEE, TRANSFER_ID] (case-sensitive) but was ' TICKER'
```

The issue is that the rendered help shows a `comma + space` separated list but the picocli parser only accepts a comma separated list without space.

**This is accepted:**

```
-i "PORTFOLIO,TICKER,TYPE"
```

**This one shows an error:**

```
-i "PORTFOLIO, TICKER, TYPE"
```

My requirement is to accept candidate list with AND without space as well and this bug confuses my users.

As a workaround, I can use a String as a type instead of List and `split + trim` the provided String but this makes my code not as elegant as it can be without this bug. Plus I need to check whether or not the provided list contains only valid enum values.

Have you ever faced this bug?

Can I instruct picocli somehow to use the value from the`split`when it renders the options?

Comment: Isn't that a matter of the shell? Under Unix the shell does word splitting and the Java program only sees multiple strings. Unless you tell the shell to not split, by using quotes.

Comment: @zappee Can you create an issue on the [picocli issue tracker](https://github.com/remkop/picocli/issues) to `trim` the values that result from `split`-ting the argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: [Custom Type Converters](https://picocli.info/#_custom_type_converters)

```
public class HeaderConverter implements CommandLine.ITypeConverter<List<Header>> {

    @Override
    public List<Header> convert(String s) throws Exception {
        List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<>();
        var params = s.split(",");
        Arrays.stream(params).forEach(x -> headers.add(Header.valueOf(x.trim())));
        return headers;
    }
}
```

This works fine, but that would be great if picocli could show candidates properly, based on the `split` parameter.